# Frontend Architecture for a web application

Tags: spring, api, rest, node.js, frontend

I have to write a new web application and currently am in the process of deciding on the architecture , there are several things i know i want to be able to do :

1. All machine must be symmetric , i.e. : commodity machines no custom build servers (aws)
2. I want a ReST API that is seperated from the UI as i allready have three clients for the API : mobile applications , the web site and a server from a 3rd company waiting for the product to be build
3. it needs to able to scale horizontal (a but of a repeat of 1)
4. Easy to maintain : no time to learn new languages , more available candidates but willing to adopt new technologies

here is the basic architecture i've come up with :

frontend combining of nginx+nodejs+expressjs+YUI , 
api : nginx+tomcat+spring framework stack (rest+Security+core+aop)

the frontend will talk to the api with oAuth 2.0

nothing exciting about the api i've done it before , i know it works and works well would have loved to put some scala flavour but i don't have the time .

my main concern is the frontend : nodejs is insanely exciting and i've been playing around for some time also love the fact it's in JS , but i'm afraid about navigation+templating+sessions (for authentication only : stateless,stateless,stateless)+logging+debugging of it , if it works it works well but it's not a mature enviourment to develop in .....

anyone here developed a full frontend with stack or subsets of it ? any other suggestions to choose from ?

thanks guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i'm afraid about navigation+templating+sessions (for
>   authentication only : stateless,stateless,stateless)+logging+debugging
>   of it

navigation?  Not sure what you mean here.  Use hyperlinks. AFAIK there's nothing in node like Rails' `form_for()` type helpers, but those were never that interesting to me.  If you want something like Rails style before/after filters, say for requiring a logged in user, connect does this great.

```
app.all('/app/*', requireUser)
```

That will call `requireUser` for any path starting with `/app`. Inside `requireUser` you can make sure `req.session.user` is there (and maybe has proper authorization).  If so, you call `next()` and the middleware responsible for actually generating the response is executed.  If the user isn't logged in or is not authorized, you can generate a 30X redirect response and don't call `next()`.  Done.  There's a great example exactly like this in the [express.js guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware). Search for `loadUser`.  This design is really elegant, IMHO.

templating?  Uh, node.js has as good or better templating options than any other platform. Try [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or any of a dozen others.  You can use the same templates on the server and in the browser, which is a nice win.  Check out [this video of Dav Glass using YUI widgets on the server side in node.js](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=f2esummit2011-glass) since you like YUI.

sessions? [Connect sessions](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html). Taste great. Less filling. What's the problem?

logging?  [Winston](https://github.com/indexzero/winston) works for me.  There are also fancier libraries as well I think.

debugging? [node-inspector](http://howtonode.org/debugging-with-node-inspector) gives node.js (IMHO) the best debugging support available.  It debugs with chrome's inspector and is every bit as awesome as debugging client side javascript. I can also debug server side unit tests when running via [jasbin](https://github.com/noblesamurai/jasbin).

Here's an answer to [what companies are using node.js in production](http://www.quora.com/Node-js/What-companies-are-using-Node-js-in-production).

Comment: thanks for the links!, by navigation i mean something like jsf navigation xml , as much as i hate JSF it's hard seeing an entire site map from links further more controling it, how do u go around implementing authentication , protecting all urls if user is not authenticated an redirecting to some login.jsp i can think of several ways but is there a framework for it ? , the fact that the server can crush due to an uncaught exception is also a concern ... have u been running nodejs in production ?

Comment: Edited my answer with more info on navigation.  You can also use `app.error` to catch errors and prevent the server from crashing.  I've been using node.js in "production" but for nano-sites used mostly by myself.

Answer (score 0):

So if you got problem with testing then you just misunderstand some features of Node.js and express. For example you can use something like this for testing:

```js
app.get('/route', function(req,res,next) {
    require('./controllers.js').method(req,res,next)
});
```

Then you need to drop cache with all files required in your controlles.js:

```js
if (require.cache[__filename])
{
  var del = false;
  for ( i in require.cache)
  {
    if (i == __filename)
    {
      del = true;
    }
    if (del)
    {
      delete require.cache[i];
    }
  }
}
```

So now your controller will updated instantly to current version when request pass.

To understand how does nodejs require work just try this:

**require.js**

```js
module.exports = {};
```

**main.js**

```js
var x = require('./require.js');
x.tell = true;
var y = require('./require.js');
y.tell = false;

console.log(require('./require.js'));
```